# Check MongoDB for uniqueness before inserting

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection containing 1 million unique numbers.

I have an operation where I will need to add something like 30,000 numbers to the collection, but if any of those numbers are already in the collection I need to cancel the operation.

Using C#, idea #1 is to do something like this:

```
private void DoImport(List<long> numbersToImport)
    {
        // brings over 1 million records from the DB. Yikes!
        var numbersInDatabase = numberRepository.GetAll();

        // convert list into a more lookup-able format
        var numbersHash = new HashSet<long>(numbersInDatabase);

        // determine if any numbers are already in the database
        var duplicates = numbersToImport.Where(number => numbersHash.Contains(number)); 
        if (duplicates.Any()) {
            // abort processing - at least one input list element is already in the database            
        }
    }
```

But there are obvious performance and scalability issues with bringing in 5 million numbers just to do a comparison.

Since I have a unique index, idea #2 is to bulk insert, and if the count of the newly inserted set does not match the count of the initial list, then remove all the new records. I don't like how this is not deterministic though. Seems like I should know more about uniqueness before I go to the database.

Is there a scalable and efficient way to check for uniqueness of a set before adding to the collection?

Comment: Is this operation something that has to happen once (a one-time import), or many times?

Comment: Once or twice a day.

Comment: [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/4de5QE26DHo) makes it sound like the entire bulk insert should fail when there's a duplicate.

Comment: I thought I had a solution, but upon further testing it didn't behave as I thought it would. Let me do some more research.